# lavaan (SEM) computing standardized coefficients manually

Tags: r, r-lavaan

How do I compute the standardized coefficients in the `lavaan` outputs?

This doesn't work for me for some reason. Not for CFA and not for SEM.

For CFA, suppose I run the following code:

```
data(HolzingerSwineford1939)
dat = HolzingerSwineford1939[,7:15]
model = 'visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3
        textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
        speed =~ x7 + x8 + x9'
fit = cfa(model, data=dat)
summary(fit, standardized=T)
```

I get the following (truncated here):

> ```
>                Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all   
> visual =~
> x1                1.000                               0.900    0.772
> x2                0.554    0.100    5.554    0.000    0.498    0.424
> x3                0.729    0.109    6.685    0.000    0.656    0.581 
> ... 
> Variances:
>                Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all    
> .x1                0.549    0.114    4.833    0.000   0.549    0.404    
> .x2                1.134    0.102   11.146    0.000    1.134    0.821    
> .x3                0.844    0.091    9.317    0.000    0.844    0.662 
> ...  
> visual            0.809    0.145    5.564    0.000    1.000    1.000
> ```

The Std.lv seems to be the original estimates `*` sd(latent).  E.g., for x2, 0.498=0.554*sqrt(0.809). (I would have thought it to be divided by, and not multiplied by, but ok).

But the Std.all doesn't seem to be this divided by the sd(variable). E.g. for x2, 0.424 != 0.554*sqrt(0.809/1.134)...

For SEM it's the same. Std.lv are equal, but std.all are not. E.g.:

```
model <- '
  # measurement model (CFA)
    ind60 =~ x1 + x2 + x3
    dem60 =~ y1 + y2 + y3 + y4
    dem65 =~ y5 + y6 + y7 + y8
  # regressions / path analysis
    dem60 ~ ind60
    dem65 ~ ind60 + dem60
  # residual correlations
    y1 ~~ y5
    y2 ~~ y4 + y6
    y3 ~~ y7
    y4 ~~ y8
    y6 ~~ y8
'
fit = sem(model, data=PoliticalDemocracy)
summary(fit, standardized=TRUE)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the Std.all doesn't seem to be this divided by the sd(variable). E.g. for x2, 0.424 != 0.554*sqrt(0.809/1.134)

1.134 is not the marginal variance, it is the residual variance.  Marginal variances are not SEM parameters, except by coincidence when a variable has not predictors.

You can use the model-implied variances on the diagonal of `lavInspect(fit, "cov.ov")` and `lavInspect(fit, "cov.lv")` to standardize coefficients between observed and/or latent variables, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem with you like this:

I am also very curious about that.
Till I find that I have normalized the scale of data to be (mean=0 and std=1)

regression  Estimate Std.Err z-value P(>|z|)  Std.lv  Std.al

```
Age              -0.610    0.165   -3.703    0.000   -0.610   -0.610
E_score           0.200    0.082    2.435    0.015    0.200    0.200
N_score           0.007    0.080    0.087    0.931    0.007    0.007
driving_year     -0.024    0.162   -0.148    0.882   -0.024   -0.024 `
```

Then I used the data of my original no-scaled data, and everything was fine.